# Google Apps Script Remove Sheet - Server error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a new sheet called new which should be overwritten if it already exists.
But when the sheet already exists I get the error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 34, file "Code")", the sheet gets removed - line 34 is the last row here:

```
  var delSheet = ss.getSheetByName("new");
  if (delSheet != null) {
  ss.deleteSheet(delSheet);
  }
  var sheet = ss.insertSheet("new");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JPVs answer is a good workaround if you want to consider it, but I could reproduce your error.

Funnily enough, if the active sheet is called 'new' and I delete the active sheet, it does not throw me an error:

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ss.getActiveSheet();
  ss.deleteActiveSheet();
  ss.insertSheet("new");
}
```

This makes me think this might be a deeper issue, specifically with '.getSheetByName()' so I've listed it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4561&thanks=4561&ts=1416774808) for review by the Google team. Please star it so it gains traction!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to 'overwrite' the sheet if it exists, try clearing instead of deleting..

```
function check() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName('new');
newSheet ? newSheet.clear() : ss.insertSheet('new');
```

}

Comment: this is not an ideal solution as it keeps the rows heights and columns widths if they have not default values... can be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a third solution, it seems that specifying a sheet index for the new sheet solves the issue.

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var delSheet = ss.getSheetByName("new");
  if (delSheet) {
    ss.deleteSheet(delSheet);
  }
  var sheet = ss.insertSheet(ss.getNumSheets());// create the new sheet as last sheet, you can change that if you want
  sheet.setName('new');
}
```

---

### EDIT :

Following HDCerberus answer that pointed the error source I suggest this code that reproduces your initial workflow (his answer does not really do so...), it uses the `deleteActiveSheet` method as well (which historically was the first available method to delete a sheet, the other method came much later...)

```
function test2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var delSheet = ss.getSheetByName("new");
  if (delSheet) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(delSheet);
    ss.deleteActiveSheet();
  }
  ss.insertSheet("new");
}
```